# Merging 2 TFS branches with old code and new layout

Tags: tfs, tfvc

in my TFS Source Control I have 2 solutions.
The first one is the old version of a ASP.NET application, and the second is the same solution with a new 
graphic layout.
The problem is that in the meantime, the solution N1 (Katalegale) has got new code functionality (no graphic modifications), and now I have to make a porting of these new only code addings to the solution N2 (Katalegale-Restyle), that has old code (code-behind in C#) but new graphic layout. 
How can I accomplish this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Ps
"Katalegale" has old graphic layout but new code.
"Katalegale-Restyle" has new graphic layout but old code.

[image: TFS Merging]

Comment: You deal with this the same way you'd deal with any divergence: Merge it. Resolve conflicts. Are you having a specific problem with performing a merge operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, you just need to perform a merge. From source branch *Katalegale* to target branch *Katalegale-Restyle*.

Merging allows to combines two different branches into one. Once more source branch and target branch are required and changes are incorporated from source branch into target branch.

Merge detects files that were added or modified inside Source Branch and will add these changes or file into Target branch. If same files on the Target Branch were modified, then **Conflict Resolution screen** will pop-up with the opportunity to **resolve the conflict**.

[image]

In your case, you may have to **manually resolve merge conflicts** to make sure branch *Katalegale-Restyle* has new graphic layout and new code.

Sample Steps:

1. If you have any files checked out, either shelve or revert them.
   That way, if you need to revert the changes you won't lose anything
   else you were working on. You also won't pollute the merge with
   changes that aren't specific to it.
2. Before doing anything, perform a **Get Latest on the target branch**
   Katalegale-Restyle. Next, right click on the Katalegalebranch, which
   is the source for the merge, and choose Branching and Merging >
   Merge from the context menu.  You can either Merge all changes up to
   the latest branch or choose specific changesets. In your scenario,
   merge should happens with the latest version of the target
   repository.
3. Click the Finish button and, if there are no conflicts, you should
   have a change set in your local work space that contains all of the
   changes since the branch was created. If there are any conflicts you
   will need to resolve each of those in turn before you are ready to
   commit the merge back into the Main branch. **Add a nice commit
   message** so that everyone knows that this is the result of a merge
   and job done.

More details about merge and resolve conflicts, please refer our official doc:

- [Merge folders and files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-folders-files?view=azure-devops)
- [Resolve Team Foundation Version Control conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Perfect Patrick, thank you very much for your detailed response.